# Background activity cursor in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouse-cursor

how can I set the Cursor on a Component to a "background activity" cursor. Like the one in Windows with the arrow and the small hourglass.

All I find ist the `Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR`, which is only an hour glass.

I found the file which contains the cursor: appstart.ani in C:\WINDOWS\Cursors can I use that somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is an animated cursor, it's not trivial to display. But the good news is that there is a tutorial for it: [Introduce Animated Cursors to Java GUIs](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187852)