# Java swing "working in background" mouse cursor

Tags: java, swing, mouse-cursor

Is there a built in cursor that will show the "arrow plus hourglass" mouse pointer that is used when windows is working in the background, yet still allowing you to click on things?
I know about WAIT_CURSOR, but I don't see anything like this. Do I need to make a custom cursor to get the hourglass-pointer combo?

Comment: I asked something similar a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042678/background-activity-cursor-in-swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a built-in cursor that does this. All the pre-defined cursors reside here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html

as you may well know.

You will need to create a custom cursor or find someone who has already done this.  Here's a website showing you how to build your own custom cursor:
http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/using-custom-cursors-in-java.html

Goodluck