# Background mouse cursor (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, cursor

A similar question has already been asked:
[Java swing "working in background" mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893911/java-swing-working-in-background-mouse-cursor)

As in the previous question, I need **"a background mouse cursor"** (wait + arrow).

In class *javafx.scene.Cursor* corresponding constant is not defined. Perhaps *JavaFX* technology has a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, there is no such predefined cursor in [`Cursor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Cursor.html)

However there is the possibility to define your own cursors:

```
Image image = new Image("batman.png");  //pass in the image path
scene.setCursor(new ImageCursor(image));
```

(Example from the tutorial https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/05/tutorial-change-default-cursor-javafx/)

See also related questions here:

- [Custom cursor set in Javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536861/custom-cursor-set-in-javafx)
- [JavaFX custom css cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168501/javafx-custom-css-cursor)